# Align RGB Depth Map with RGB image without intrinsic matrix

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, realsense

I have pairs of image - an image (blurred intentionally) and its depth map (given as PNG).

For example:
[image]

However, there seems to be a shift between the depth map and the real image as can be seen in this example:
[image]

All i know that these images were shot with a RealSense LiDAR Camera **L515** (I do not have knowledge of the underlying camera characteristics or the distance between both rgb and infrared sensors).

Is there a way to align both images? I searched the internet for possible solutions. However, all solutions rely on data that I do not have, such as the intrinsic matrix, cameras SDK and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the two imaging systems are very close physically, the homography between them would likely be a good approximation. You can find the homography using 4 corresponding points that you choose manually.

You can use the OpenvCV [implementation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4b3841447530523e5272ec05c5d1e411).